# Cant use Broadcom wifi on my LenovoG500 Laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, 20.10

```
ejac@ejac-Lenovo-G500:~$ lshw -c network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0400000-e0407fff

ejac@ejac-Lenovo-G500:~$ lspci
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

- I've done an update & upgrade them following up this instructions:
  [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
- I've purged the bcmwl-kernel-source
- updated the pciids
- installed the bcmwl-kernel-source
- installed the linux-firmware
- rebooted
- update & upgrade again

yet I still don't have WIFI.

Additional logs as requested:

```
ejac@ejac-Lenovo-G500:~$ sudo modprobe wl && sudo dmesg | grep wl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Key was rejected by service
ejac@ejac-Lenovo-G500:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe wl && sudo dmesg | grep wl` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please temporarily turn off Secure Boot and try again. Possibly helpful: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/394

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: As stated by chili555 disabling the secure boot from the BIOS fixed the problem. I have wifi now. I have no idea why secure boot would interfere with broadcom drivers but thank you chili555.

Comment: Secure Boot doesn't led to load any 3rd party unsigned drivers.